# How to Close Sidebar menu dropdown when the user opens second dropdown in adminlte?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, adminlte

Hi I am using adminlte for my website. What I want to do is in sidebar when dropdown is opened and user wants to open second dropdown the first one closes automatically.

For example if the products dropdown is opened and then I want to see customers type of that product, if I click the sales dropdown the products down should be closed.

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-light-primary elevation-4">
  <!-- Brand Logo -->
  <a href="#" class="brand-link bg-dark">
    <img src="dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3"
      style="opacity: .8">
    <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">AdminLTE 3</span>
  </a>

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
    <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <a href="#" class="d-block">Alexander Pierce</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
    <nav class="mt-2">
      <ul id="main-side" class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu"
        data-accordion="false">
        <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
           with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->


        <li class="nav-item has-treeview ">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            <p>
              Products
              <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
            </p>
          </a>
          <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
            <div class=" p-2">
              <div class="form-inline  input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" name="" id="" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                  aria-label="">

              </div>

              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-1 ml-1">
                <input class="custom-control-input " type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="">
                <label class="custom-control-label " for="">Select All</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style="height: 150px;" class="overflow-auto">
              <li class="nav-item pl-5">
                <p class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="" value="">
                  <label for="" class="custom-control-label ">Mango</label>
                </p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item pl-5">
                <p class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="" value="">
                  <label for="" class="custom-control-label ">Grapes</label>
                </p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item pl-5">
                <p class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="" value="">
                  <label for="" class="custom-control-label ">Apple</label>
                </p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item pl-5">
                <p class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="" value="">
                  <label for="" class="custom-control-label ">Oranges</label>
                </p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item pl-5">
                <p class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="" value="">
                  <label for="" class="custom-control-label ">Banana</label>
                </p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- Products End -->
        <!-- Customer Type Starts -->
        <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link ">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-store-alt"></i>
            <p>
              Customer Types
              <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
            </p>
          </a>
          <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
            <div class=" p-2">

              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mt-1 ml-1">
                <input class="custom-control-input " type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="">
                <label class="custom-control-label " for="">Select All</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <li class="nav-item pl-5">
                <p class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="" value="">
                  <label for="" class="custom-control-label ">Large Retail</label>
                </p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item pl-5">
                <p class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="" value="">
                  <label for="" class="custom-control-label ">Modern Trade</label>
                </p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item pl-5">
                <p class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="" value="">
                  <label for="" class="custom-control-label ">Whole Sale</label>
                </p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item pl-5">
                <p class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="" value="">
                  <label for="" class="custom-control-label ">Small Retail</label>
                </p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </li>


      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>
```

So far I Have tried this code.

```
$('.has-treeview').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('menu-open')){
    $(this).removeClass('menu-open');
  }
  else{
    $(this).addClass('menu-open');
  }
})
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I Have tried this `  $('.has-treeview').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('menu-open')){
      $(this).removeClass('menu-open');
    }
    else{
      $(this).addClass('menu-open');
    }
  })`

Comment: Thank you  for ahelping me out . i have found the solution and answered it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul id="main-side" class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
```

Just remove data-accordion = "false"

Comment: This is definitely the solution, it's in the documentation but not so easy to find, thanks!
https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/javascript/treeview.html

Answer (score 0):

By doing lot of google and code experiments i have the thing that i wanted.

```
    $('#main-side .has-treeview').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.menu-open').removeClass('menu-open').children('.nav-treeview').slideToggle();
  })
```